# session_destroy() does not destroy $_SESSION datas?

Tags: php

I am really confused about `session_destroy()` function in PHP. I read in the php manual that it destroys all data registered to a session. What exactly does that mean?

When I tried to echo a result that I stored in `$_SESSION` after `session_destroy()`, it still gets printed!

I just thought results stored in the `$_SESSION` are the datas registered to a session.
If that is wrong then what are the datas that exactly php manual is trying to convey.
Need a guidance.

```
session_start();  
class Student  
{  
    public $name;  
    public $id;  
    function setName($param)  
    {  
        return $this->name=$param;  
    }   
}  
$student_1=new Student();  
$stu=$student_1->setName("Abhinav");  
$_SESSION["name1"]=$stu;  
session_destroy();  
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Show your code first.

Comment: you have to start the session before destroying it , are you doing that .. i mean besfore session_destroy(); add this line session_start(); if you ahven't already

Comment: Even after using session_deatroy, the name is still getting printed. So if that function does not destroy the $_SESSION datas, wht does that exactly destroy?

Comment: @user2401175 - among other things, it deletes the persistent storage (typically temp file) used for storing the session data between requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simplty do:

`$_SESSION = [];`

but this is advised against. So what I use is:

```
<?php 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: hey...thanx this worked but just for the info i want to know that if session_destroy() does not destroys those datas in $_SESSION thn wht does that exactly destroy?

Comment: It destroys the data stored on the disk for the session, not the in-memory data.

Comment: I noticed that session_destroy does not clear the data from $_SESSION from the current request but does it for any subsequent one.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the manual](http://php.net/session_destroy)

`session_destroy()` destroys all of the data associated with the current session. **It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session**, or unset the session cookie

Comment: Thts my doubt....wht does "destroys all of the data associated with current session" means?

Comment: By default session data is stored on a file on the server. Destroying the session erases the file so the next time the page is loaded you won't have the same session.

Comment: Okay...so even though the file is deleted from the serverm is it still maintained in the $_SESSION array variable?

Comment: By the time your script has started PHP has already loaded the file into the $_SESSION variable. Destroying that file during the execution of your script is not going to do anything to $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

Before session_destry() start session and unset all values.

```
unset($_SESSION["variable"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`session_destroy()` destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

To destroy session completely you may use `unset()`

```
unset($_SESSION);
```

it will remove each and every thing from `$_SESSION`.
OR
You can also set `$_SESSION` to an empty array

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Session used to transfer data between pages of website. Even you destroy session using session_destroy() data will not erase from $_SESSION, but when you access another page of website there will be no data in $_SESSION array.